# why some xlsx files open in browser when launched from SharePoint site

Tags: excel, google-chrome, sharepoint

The excel file is getting opened in a new tab when I launch the file from Microsoft SharePoint. But after downloading the file and access it from the chrome browser, it does not open in chrome instead it opens directly in the installed application(MS-Excel). Is there any reason for this, how does chrome know to render in chrome when it opened from share point and not from another source?

Comment: I believe it's *SharePoint* (Office365) that's doing the rendering, *before* it's sent to your browser.

Comment: Ok. Thanks for your reply.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@mark,

You can change the settings in “Advanced settings”:

[image]

In the document library settings click on “Advanced settings” which is under “General Settings”. Go to “Opening Documents in the Browser” section and choose either “Open in the browser” or “Use the server default (Open in the browser)” option.

BR

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I just wanted to know the reason why this feature is auto-enabled when the documents launched from share point but not from other sources. I think this answer will help someone who wants to open the documents in the browser.

Comment: exactly it's render in office online not chrome. when it needs to open excel file in browser it will call office online web service through chrome.

Comment: Thanks, @Baker_Kong_MSFT.  @ paulsm4 has commented the same which answers my question already. The answer that you posted is not in my question("How to"). Shall I accept it or you want to update the answer?